# how to send an email to a particular email id using Klaviyo in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, klaviyo

https://developers.klaviyo.com/
Is there any api or method or any way to send an email to a particular mail id through the Klaviyo api or any sdk or any other way ? for the nodejs application.

api refrence on any way to send email by klaviyo

please if any one got solution share